# Get top 4 highest rows based on ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to grab the highest 4 rows in a table and assign variables to them so that I can use them throughout my code.

Here is what I was able to get so far...

```
        <?php
$username="USERNAME";
$password="PASSWORD";
$database="DATABASE";
$conn = mysqli_connect(localhost, $username, $password, $database);

$query = "SELECT * from `shoutbox` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4";
$result = $conn->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $name =($row["name"]);
              $message =($row["message"]); 
              $time =($row["time"]); 
    }


?>
```

How am I able to assign more variables to get the next 3 rows?

Comment: `$results = array(); ... $results[] = $row;` PS: parentheses around variables are redundant and look odd.

Comment: Or you can use the variables you created for each iteration, serves the same purpose usually.

Comment: @zerkms I never really learned arrays to be honest and I'm not sure how I would go about doing that =/

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Well as it is right now, `$name` gives the name from the newest id, How would I go about assigning variables for the other ids?

Comment: @pshyoulost so a good time to learn them. Especially after knowing you already use them: `$row` is an array.

Comment: Because you access `$name` outside the loop. If you echo it inside the loop you will see 3 names for 3 rows

Comment: Look into using prepared statements for your SQL btw.

Comment: @Outsider but it's not parameterized. What is the point?

Comment: @zerkms this code it's useless, but considering he's currently asking about arrays and planning on doing Database stuff, it's something he'll obviously need to know is all.  It's only a short step from here after all to doing user input queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's (sorry, long day so I might be off)

```
$result = array();
while(...){
      $result[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about setting it up? http://pastebin.com/Pbq04Vym . Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @pshyoulost so where did the `[1]` come from? And why the hell do you put parentheses everywhere?!

Comment: @zerkms I kinda pulled it out of my ass! I don't know! That's how it was taught to me!!

Comment: So how about you learn basics before you continue programming? You really produce a mess. Not to say we care much, but maintenance of your code will make someone angry after some time.

Comment: something like this: http://pastebin.com/YmQ3xK06

It might be off, I didn't run it, I haven't done PHP in a couple months and I should be sleep, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: @Outsider just one thing: in php there is no reason to prefer `for` over `foreach` and the latter is more convenient

Comment: @zerkms You're completely right, I've just been doing a lot of C++ coding recently and it slipped my mind that was a thing, haha.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you loop through the result set and assign each iteration to an array, you can then pull the values back out of the array later.
Here is a working update to your code

```
// ...
$query = "SELECT * from `shoutbox` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4";
$result = $conn->query($query);

// create array to hold queried result set
$output = array();

// loop through result set and assign each row to a key in $output array
// Note: the fetch_assoc() method auto-increments an internal pointer 
// so as you spin through the result set $row will move down the rows
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

// $output now contains an associative array on each key representing
// each row, so to access each row:
foreach($output as $row) {
    echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
    echo $row["message"] . "<br>";
    echo $row["message"] . "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `$result` as array after while

```
$result = array();
while($row= .... ){
$var= $row['name'];
.............
}
```